# Transferring files remotely from Windows to Mac makes filenames lowercase

Tags: macos, content-management-system, remote-access, f5

When a Mac laptop connects to a Windows machine through F5+RDC, and attempts to transfer files/folders from the windows machine to Mac hard drive, the files/folders become lower case in the name field. (RDC is Remote Desktop Connection, and F5 is another remote access application) When the folder is renamed with uppercase letters, the file/folder reverts back to lowercase (If attempted through RDC). This happens in all cases of renaming and editing the files or folders on the Mac hard drive while connected to the Windows machine. The initial problem was that transferring files and folders from a CMS to the Mac HD changed text on file names/folders to lower case. This is a problem for Mac users who need to access the Windows machine we have. It's extremely important that the files/folders case remain intact.

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT6Dk.jpg

For reasons, acquiring files/folders needs to be done this way through people who use Mac computers at our workplace.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the old version of RDC with the new version: 8.0.18 and it solved the problem. The new version has a different way of mapping paths so something related to that could have corrected the issue.